# How avoid shifting of x axis in seaborn with two plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to plot a graph with multiple plots. Unfortunately my line plot is shifted to the left. I found that `lineplot()` function sees x axis as numerical values. As a result, this shift is due to the no observations of  `Dummy=no` in `'2018 Q4','2019 Q1','2019 Q2'`. Could you help to solve the problem and make `lineplot()` to correspond to correct x axis values?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'time':['2018 Q4','2019 Q1','2019 Q2','2019 Q3','2019 Q3','2019 Q4','2019 Q4',],
                   'Dummy' : ['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','yes','no',],
                    'Value': [667,666,668,500,121,520,130],
                        'Change' : [100,100,100,60,40,30,70]
                   })


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
sns.barplot(data=df, x="time", y="Value"  , hue="Dummy", alpha=.6, ax=ax1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data = df[df['Dummy'] == 'no'], x = 'time',y = 'Change', sort = False, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#why-cant-i-draw-a-line-over-a-barboxstripviolin-plot

Comment: If the time column is made a categorical variable, the issue is resolved. `df['time'] = df['time'].astype('category') `